# A boy who talks disturbs others

Tags: sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

I am really confused about the complex, compound and simple sentences. 
I am looking for the answer. I read about them on different pages, means I used Google to  understand them but all in vain.

A boy who talks disturbs others. 
Whether the sentence is compound, complex or simple? 
One of my teachers told me that it's a compound sentence,  he said,  "who talks" is relative clause and "a boy disturbs" is main clause. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These seem like [reasonable definitions](http://www.theschoolrun.com/what-are-simple-compound-and-complex-sentences-0). 1: *A **compound sentence** is formed when you join **two main clauses** with a connective.* Not that, obviously, since all you've got is an embedded *relative clause*. 2: *A **complex sentence** is formed when you join **a main clause and a subordinate clause with a connective.*** I don't really think you can say ***who talks*** is a clause containing a "connective", so it's not that either. It's just a simple sentence, to the extent such a classification is "useful".

Comment: Things might be different if you're trying to analyse, say, *Your son, **who talks in class,** disturbs others.* But what *good* is this kind of analysis for learning English?

Answer (score 4):

First, a clause is a group of words with a subject, a verb and an object (it's not always the case).

A **simple sentence** has one clause.

> A boy disturbs others. / A boy talks.

A **compound sentence** has two or more independent clauses. An independant clause is a clause that doesn't depend on another one (it can make sense on its own) and that has no one depending on it.

> A boy talks and disturbs others.
>
> A boy talks so he disturbs others. 
>   (The second clause is linked to the first one with the coordination conjunction)

A **complex sentence** has one or more dependent (or subordinate) clauses. A dependant sentence depends on the main clause and cannot make sense on its own as a sentence.

> A boy who talks disturbs others.

The main clause is *A boy disturbs others* and the dependent clause is *who talks*. It modifies *boy*.

Taking into account this information, your sentence is likely **complex**.

Comment: If we contrast, say *A crying boy disturbs others* or *A boy crying disturbs others* with *A boy who cries disturbs others*, I think it's stretching a point to call the first two "simple" and the last one "complex". But what do I know?

Comment: In the two first sentences, there is only one clause, because *crying* is either an adjective or a participle.

Comment: I understand the point. I just don't ***see*** the point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a matter of fact that in the last one there's a embedded clause; I made a quick (not entirely accurate) [tree of it](http://i.imgur.com/glMqC2A.png). I don't think calling it _complex_ vs. _simple_ really helps, but the idea of clause embedding is important syntactically.

Comment: In the final analysis, I just think this is "an analysis too far" for most contexts. But yes - if your task is to create a tree diagram, you do need to split off ***who talks*** as a single element before breaking it down further. You'd have to do the same with *A boy **crying continually** disturbs others*, even though by convention we wouldn't call that a "clause". The question has been asked, and you've answered it, but I don't see *Is this a clause?* as very helpful, so I don't think I'll be voting on this page.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **Crying continually** is a reduced relative clause, linguistically. Whether a reduced relative clause is a true relative clause or not, and how it's structured internally, is something more complex.

Comment: @eijen: Spare me! :) I did a year of linguistics as part of my degree many decades ago, but I certainly wouldn't have bothered going in to the lectures if they'd kept shoveling such fine points of grammatical terminology down my neck! I can't help wondering if a question like this might not be better suited to [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions) though. Or even [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).